# Help identify the chip company and chip ID

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

This is a chip on board an Asus RTX 4090. The image is from https://youtu.be/q_kWonOzoag?t=257

Here is another higher resolution image of the same:

https://www.techpowerup.com/review/asus-geforce-rtx-4090-strix-oc/4.html

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently SAP stands for "super alloy power" - which is the most effort anyone has ever put into making an inductor sound cool.

> ASUS deployed its latest Super Alloy Power II (SAP II) component selection, consisting of chokes that don't buzz or whine; and high quality DrMOS.

https://www.techpowerup.com/forums/threads/asus-rog-strix-radeon-rx-5700-xt-oc-detailed-some-more.258074/

A web search for "super alloy power" gets you on the hype train for ASUS graphics cards, but doesn't yield a lot of specifications for the inductors themselves, which could be different for different graphics cards with this SAP II system.

Comment: Hehe, these gaming hardware companies are a bit on the ridiculous side. (Why any gamer PC looks like an UFO just landed and when all those fans of the gfx card go on, the UFO might just as well take off too.) Coil whine has been a longstanding problem with gfx cards so I guess this would be some marketing fluff to make gamers think "wow this got silent coils". Sexier than "we decided to finally fix the actual, long-standing EMC problems on our CE mark violating products" I guess... (A PC being an audio product so any PC component giving out spurious sound is non-conforming to EMC)

Comment: i was reading it as ZAP, DAZ, DVS, and SAD the funniest was II SAD, i would have never got to Super Alloy Power !!!

Answer (score 3):

That is an inductor! These are used commonly in power stages of graphic cards for Core voltage and Memory voltage.